# mysql sorting cells with letters and words

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, datatables

I got cells that might have the following data (number of errors)

```
1
2
3
PASS
NoFileFound
NoLog
99
10
2
```

I would like sort with ascending order and descending order where I would PASS to be treated as a value of 0 and any other text based value should be treated as value of 1 error. As of now, these cells are stored as 'text' in the mysql database. How can this be done for MYSQL? What changes do I need to do?

Comment: have you tried out my solution already below? Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT Number FROM (
   SELECT IF(valueField='PASS',0,1) as Number  FROM TableMix 
   WHERE concat('',valueField * 1) <> valueField ) A
UNION ALL
SELECT Number FROM (
  SELECT CAST(valueField as UNSIGNED) as Number  FROM TableMix 
  WHERE concat('',valueField * 1) = valueField ) B
ORDER BY Number
```

See my [SqlFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/343d7/6)

And this one with original values included:

```
SELECT Number, valueField FROM (
   SELECT IF(valueField='PASS',0,1) as Number, valueField  FROM TableMix 
   WHERE concat('',valueField * 1) <> valueField ) A
UNION ALL
SELECT Number, valueField FROM (
  SELECT CAST(valueField as UNSIGNED) as Number, valueField  FROM TableMix 
  WHERE concat('',valueField * 1) = valueField ) B
ORDER BY Number
```

See this [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/343d7/5).

Comment: I haven't given this a try yet. I have to modified an existing perl package for datatables which uses ORDER BY syntax only.